# Объясните спецификатор

Tags: c

Использовал в scanf спецификатор " %[^\r\n]" для того, чтобы мог вводить название из нескольких слов,отделенных пробелами.(посоветовали так же на форуме это спецификатор использовать), но как его объяснить.Почему в квадратных скобках?
Что означает "^" крышечка? 
Коротко говоря подробно написать саму работу данного спецификатора.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Читайте документацию по `scanf`, там все подробно написано.

Спецификатор формата вида `%[что-то]` означает "читать все символы, пока они принадлежат набору, указанному в квадратных скобках".

Спецификатор формата вида `%[^что-то]` означает "читать все символы, пока они НЕ принадлежат набору, указанному в квадратных скобках" (т.е "читать все символы, пока не наткнешься на один из указанных в квадратных скобках").

В вашем случае `" %[^\r\n]"` означает: пропустить ведущие пробелы и затем читать все подряд, пока не наткнешься на `'\r'` или `'\n'`.

---

Вообще-то, если речь не идет о каких-то тонкостях, связанных с обработкой символа `'\r'`, `scanf` с форматом `" %[^\r\n]"` означает просто "пропустить ведущие пробелы и затем читать до конца строки", при этом оставляя символы конца строки непрочитанными. Это примерно то же самое, что и обычный `fgets`, с той только разницей, что `fgets` не пропускает ведущие пробелы и вычитывает из потока символы конца строки. Может быть вам лучше подойдет просто `fgets` и не надо городить огород с этим `%[]`?

Также не ясно, зачем понадобилась отдельная обработка символа `'\r'`. Если речь идет о чтении текстового потока под Windows, то там никакого `'\r'` уже не будет. Все маркеры конца строки будут заменены на простое `'\n'` еще до того, как дело дойдет до `scanf`.

Также имейте в виду, что `scanf` не умеет читать пустые строки. То есть если этот `%[^\r\n]` сразу же наткнется на `'\r'` или `'\n'`, то `scanf` тут же завершится с ошибкой, не изменив значение принимающего буфера.